# Postgres array comparison - find missing elements

Tags: postgresql, array-difference

I have the table below.

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║id                  ║arr1                ║arr2         ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║1                   ║{1,2,3,4}           ║{2,1,7}      ║
║2                   ║{0}                 ║{3,4,5}      ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to find out the elements which are in arr1 and not in arr2. 
Expected output

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║id                  ║diff                ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╣             
║1                   ║{3,4}               ║      
║2                   ║{0}                 ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

If I have 2 individual arrays, I can do as follows:

```
select array_agg(elements)
from (
  select unnest(array[0])
  except
  select unnest(array[3,4,5])
) t (elements)
```

But I am unable to integrate this code to work by selecting from my table.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Such a function is already provided by the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) module. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a function for this:

```
create function array_diff(p_one int[], p_other int[])
  returns int[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(item)
  from (
     select *
     from unnest(p_one) item
     except
     select *
     from unnest(p_other)
  ) t 
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select id, array_diff(arr1, arr2)
from the_table
```

---

A much faster alternative is to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) module and use

```
select id, arr1 - arr2
from the_table
```

Comment: Why not make it even more generic and reusable like `array_diff(p_one anyarray, p_other anyarray) returns anyarray` with the same body.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: no specific reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `except` for each id and after that group by for each group

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dd156509e3267011abb478c212a532ad)

```sql
with diff_data as (
    select id, unnest(arr1) as data
    from test_table
        except
    select id, unnest(arr2) as data
    from test_table
)
select id, array_agg(data order by data) as diff
from diff_data
group by id
```